# Question on series

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Suppose $ a_i $ be a sequence of positive real numbers such that $ \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_i < \infty $. Is it true that $ \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \log(i) \cdot a_i < \infty $?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, a counterexample is $a_n = \frac{1}{n \log^2 n}$.